# Get name of window which is being closed using automation events c#

Tags: c#, event-handling, ui-automation, automationelement

I'm working on a project where I **need to get the name of windows which is being closed**.
I'm **using C# Automation events** for this.

I've pasted below the code that I'm using:

```
Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent,
AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Subtree, (sender, eve) =>
{
    AutomationElement winElemnt = sender as AutomationElement;
    if (winElemnt != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window closed : " + winElemnt.Current.Name);
    }
 });
```

The above code get triggered when any window closes but I'm getting following error on execution:

1. Value of variable *sender* will be *null*.
2. Unable to get automation element's *Current.Name* (I'm getting this error most of the time)

**On debugging** I was able to find that the **2nd error is due to window closing before completing event handler execution**.

Please let me know how to fix these errors and get the name of window for which close is triggered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: simple tip:Why not do something specific on each window's `Closing` event like passing the name to a `My.Settings` variable or any global string variable that may hold their names? then retieve them back ?

Comment: @zackraiyan its a part of automation project and here window close can happen due to multiple reasons. So its best for me to work with event handlers

Comment: ow,i understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use [caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/use-caching-in-ui-automation) to be able to retrieve the property when the window closes since the automation element will be gone.

The remarks for the WindowPattern says the following

> A client application may need to listen for WindowClosedEvent from a
>   cached object since a window is removed from the UI Automation control
>   view structure immediately upon being closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it says in the [documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowclosedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When your application receives a window-closed event, the sender
>   parameter of the event handler cannot be used to obtain information
>   about the window that has closed, because the corresponding UI
>   Automation element is no longer valid.

I'm afraid you'll have to find another way to get the window name.

Comment: Is there any other way using event handlers??